# Inserting a Hyphen in between a composite primary key

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, composite-types, cockroachdb

I have more of a conceptual question. Is there a way to model the following:

```
  CREATE TABLE AssetPair (
      older_asset_id INT8,
      newer_asset_id INT8,
      PRIMARY KEY (older_asset_id, '-', newer_asset_id)
  );
```

My issue is that `older_asset_id` and `newer_asset_id` are incrementing IDs so the following edgecases are possible:

```
older_asset_id: 1, newer_asset_id: 234 --> PrimaryKey:1234
// same Primary keys
older_asset_id: 12 newer_asset_id: 34 --> PrimaryKey:1234
```

If I was able to insert a hyphen between the two columns I'd be able to avoid this issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how composite keys work. A composite key looks at each column individually, not concatenated.

This is all you need to enforce integrity

```
CREATE TABLE AssetPair (
      older_asset_id INT8,
      newer_asset_id INT8,
      PRIMARY KEY (older_asset_id, newer_asset_id)
);
```

You can see this in action in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fCqkEcc_).

Comment: Yup you're right, figured that out shortly after posting but thank you for your response all the same!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed column based on the two id fields.

```
create table asset_pair (                                                                                                           
  oldid int not null,                                                                                                          
  newid int not null,                                                                                                          
  compositeid string not null as ( oldid || '-' || newid ) stored,                                                             
  primary key ( compositeid )                                                                                                  
);
```